# Python - Complement of range-based sublist selection

Tags: python, list, range

I was wondering if there is a python "core" syntax to handle complement of range-based selections.

Say that

```
 a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

then, for instance,

```
 offset = 1
 step = 3
 a[offset::step] = [1,4].
```

My question hence is:

"Can I do like

```
 a[~(offset::step)] == [0,2,3,5,6]
```

without using `ifs`?"

Or, "what is the most *pythonic* way to handle this?"

**Addendum:**

say that I have to do this sub-sampling operation for thousands of lists (indeed trajectories of particles) of variable size (i.e. trajectories of variable time length). So I cannot pre-calculate the correct index set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sets are (usually) about an order of magnitude faster, even if you don't populate the indices ahead of time:

```
r100 = range(100)
r2 = range(3, 40, 3)

# Find indices in r100 that aren't in r2.
# This is a set difference (or symmetric difference)
## Set methods
# Precalculated is fastest:
sr100 = set(r100)
sr2 = set(r2)
%timeit sr100 - sr2
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.84 us per loop

# Non-precalculated is still faster:
%timeit set(range(100)) ^ set(range(3,40,3))
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.76 us per loop
%timeit set(xrange(100)) ^ set(xrange(3,40,3))
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.84 us per loop

# Precalculating the original indices still helps, if you can hold it in memory:
%timeit sr100 ^ set(xrange(3,40,3))
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.87 us per loop

# This is true even including converting back to list, and sorting (if necessary):
%timeit [x for x in sr100 ^ set(xrange(3,40,3))]
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.02 us per loop
%timeit sorted(x for x in sr100 ^ set(xrange(3,40,3)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 15 us per loop


## List comprehension:

# Precalculated indices
%timeit [x for x in r100 if x not in r2]
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.5 us per loop

# Non-precalculated indices, using xrange
%timeit [x for x in xrange(100) if x not in xrange(3, 40, 3)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 65.8 us per loop

# The cost appears to be in the second xrange?
%timeit [x for x in r100 if x not in xrange(3, 40, 3)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 64.3 us per loop
%timeit [x for x in xrange(100) if x not in r2]
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.9 us per loop
# xrange is not really any faster than range here - uses less memory, but still have
# to walk through entire list
%timeit [x for x in range(100) if x not in range(3, 40, 3)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.5 us per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to generate the indices, then use a list comprehension to select all values not matching those indices. Use a `range()` object for an efficient method to test for indices (`xrange()` in python 2):

```
indices = range(offset, len(a), step)
[v for i, v in enumerate(a) if i not in indices]
```

The `range()` object in Python 3 (`xrange()` in Python 2) only holds the start, end, and step values, `in` tests simply do a quick calculation if the tested value is part of the range.

Demo:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> offset, step = 1, 3
>>> indices = range(offset, len(a), step)
>>> indices
range(1, 7, 3)
>>> [v for i, v in enumerate(a) if i not in indices]
[0, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Yes, this still requires using an `if` statement, but the test is cheap and can be incorporated in a generator expression as needed:

```
for i in (v for i, v in enumerate(a) if i not in range(offset, len(a), step)):
```

Comment: I see, so via `xrange` I am not computing the whole index set. This is supposedly quicker.

Comment: @Acorbe: `xrange()` membership tests have constant cost, yes.

Answer (score 0):

While still using an if, the following is a single step list comprehension that I believe gives you the required answer:

```
>>> offset = 1
>>> step = 3
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> [v for i, v in enumerate(a) if not i%step == offset]
[0, 2, 3, 5, 6]
>>>
```

What I don't know is if this is more or less efficient than using the range construct over mod.